# How to get the body response in a request

Tags: http, go, request, webserver, response

I'm trying to make a webserver that will work like a proxy. My server make requests (POST, GET ...) for the client to an specific site, receive the response from this site and give it to the client. As i said, like a proxy. The problem is: in the response from google.com for example (or any other site) i can't read the body. The status code is 200 but when i tried to read the body content i receive weird things.

This is the part of my code that i make the request

```
request, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
for k, v := range m {
    request.Header.Set(k, v)
}
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err.Error())
}

client := http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(request)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err.Error())
}else{

fmt.Println("=======================")
fmt.Println(resp)
fmt.Println("=======================")
fmt.Println(resp.Body)
```

And i receive this:

```
=======================
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Date:[Mon, 09 Jan 2017 18:07:49 GMT]
Cache-Control:[private, max-age=0] Content-Type:[text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1] P3p:[CP="This is not a P3P policy! See 
https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more 
info."] Server:[gws] X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] Expires:[-1] X-
Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] Set-Cookie:[NID=94=i5qZWuqYtrLAkc-amGHbmDnqx3Wg8mGx0kuk6s-
gKWYMSNXbScl0Cb5GldDzGdfrIrJvHC3151JzHB2s3XLdmFN82-
_gSxu07xwPNbVlzKiZgE9dJf7vXeXSaYQhWowv; expires=Tue, 11-Jul-2017 
18:07:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com.br; HttpOnly]] 0xc4200cac20 
-1 [] false true map[] 0xc420126000 <nil>}
=======================
&{0xc420014700 <nil> <nil>}
```

Comment: The response body is an [io.ReadCloser](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser). Show the code that you use to [read](https://godoc.org/io#Reader.Read) the body.

Comment: You haven't tried to read the body, you've just printed the Response.Body structure.

Comment: Yes, I thought the body content was in the Response.Body structure. So how do I get the body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation at https://golang.org/pkg/net/http, to read the body of the response you can use [`io.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#ReadAll).

```golang
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
        // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Side note: You can also use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#ReadAll) instead of `io.ReadAll`, but the `ioutil` documentation says:

> As of Go 1.16, the same functionality is now provided by package io or package os, and those implementations should be preferred in new code.

Comment: you can _use_ `ioutil` to read an `io.Reader`, but you don't _need_ it.

Comment: Read can block though.

Comment: `Read` can block, and thus `ReadAll` can block, too, but in order to do something useful with the response body you will have to read it at _some_ point though?

Comment: @JimB: Good point. Since then, the answer was edited to say "you can use" instead of "you need to use".